# iPad just updated now shows double icon rows

Tags: ipad

Anyone seen this before?  After updating an iPad to the latest OS now all rows of icons are duplicated.  They also seem to wiggle a bit.  Hard reboot with home and power button do nothing for the problem.

[image]

Comment: To clarify, you updated the iPad to iOS 11.2.1? What version of iOS were you running before this issue occurred? Lastly, if you lock the device, are there any issues on the lock screen?

Comment: Yes 11.2.1.  I don't know for sure what the OS version was prior to this but it was fairly recent.  I can't get the user (parents) to understand how to lock the device.  They're saying the lock button doesn't do anything just stays on the same screen.